# UART in NON INTERRUPT or INTERRUPT mode while using VUSB

Tags: avr, atmega, uart, usb-device

I'm working UART data transfer from one ATmega8 to other while the receiver runs VUSB acting as HID Mouse to the PC.

UART though init with 9600 , later is set to max speed - > UBRR = 0;

Problems :

1. VUSB isnt stable on both interrupt based comm. or non interrupt based comm.
2. I was succesfull to have it stable only once .. but the data received was garbage.

How do I overcome these problems ..

made a small protocol for data ..

SYNC_START    X     Y     END_SYNC

the transmitter code:

```
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//Defines
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
#define F_CPU       16000000UL
#define true        0x01
#define false       0x00
#define uchar       unsigned char
#define uint        unsigned int

#define START_SYNC_BYTE 0b10101010
#define END_SYNC_BYTE   0b01010101
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

#include <avr/io.h>
#include <util/delay.h>

#include "uart/UART.h"
#include "IMU.h"

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//GLOBAL VARIABLES
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
uint X=0,Y=0;
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


int main(void)
{
    i2c_init();
    WakeUpIMU();

    UART_Init(9600,true,false,false);

    UBRRH = 0;
    UBRRL = 0;


    while(1)
    {
        X = Get16Bits(MPU6050_RA_ACCEL_XOUT_H);
        Y = Get16Bits(MPU6050_RA_ACCEL_YOUT_H);

        BlockingTransmitt(START_SYNC_BYTE);
        BlockingTransmitt(START_SYNC_BYTE);
        BlockingTransmitt(X);
        BlockingTransmitt(Y);
        BlockingTransmitt(END_SYNC_BYTE);

        _delay_ms(5);
    }
}
```

The receiver Code :

```
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//Defines
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
#define F_CPU       16000000UL
#define true        0x01
#define false       0x00
#define uchar       unsigned char
#define uint        unsigned int

#define START_SYNC_BYTE 0b10101010
#define END_SYNC_BYTE   0b01010101
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

#include <avr/io.h>
#include <avr/wdt.h>
#include <avr/interrupt.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <util/delay.h>

#include "uart/UART.h"
#include "usbdrv/usbdrv.h"

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//GLOBAL VARIABLES
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
uint X,Y;
bool WaitingForX=false,WaitingForY=false;
bool TransmissionComplete = false;
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////



PROGMEM const char usbHidReportDescriptor[52] =
{ /* USB report descriptor, size must match usbconfig.h */
    0x05, 0x01,                    // USAGE_PAGE (Generic Desktop)
    0x09, 0x02,                    // USAGE (Mouse)
    0xa1, 0x01,                    // COLLECTION (Application)
    0x09, 0x01,                    //   USAGE (Pointer)
    0xA1, 0x00,                    //   COLLECTION (Physical)
    0x05, 0x09,                    //     USAGE_PAGE (Button)
    0x19, 0x01,                    //     USAGE_MINIMUM
    0x29, 0x03,                    //     USAGE_MAXIMUM
    0x15, 0x00,                    //     LOGICAL_MINIMUM (0)
    0x25, 0x01,                    //     LOGICAL_MAXIMUM (1)
    0x95, 0x03,                    //     REPORT_COUNT (3)
    0x75, 0x01,                    //     REPORT_SIZE (1)
    0x81, 0x02,                    //     INPUT (Data,Var,Abs)
    0x95, 0x01,                    //     REPORT_COUNT (1)
    0x75, 0x05,                    //     REPORT_SIZE (5)
    0x81, 0x03,                    //     INPUT (Const,Var,Abs)
    0x05, 0x01,                    //     USAGE_PAGE (Generic Desktop)
    0x09, 0x30,                    //     USAGE (X)
    0x09, 0x31,                    //     USAGE (Y)
    0x09, 0x38,                    //     USAGE (Wheel)
    0x15, 0x81,                    //     LOGICAL_MINIMUM (-127)
    0x25, 0x7F,                    //     LOGICAL_MAXIMUM (127)
    0x75, 0x08,                    //     REPORT_SIZE (8)
    0x95, 0x03,                    //     REPORT_COUNT (3)
    0x81, 0x06,                    //     INPUT (Data,Var,Rel)
    0xC0,                          //   END_COLLECTION
    0xC0,                          // END COLLECTION
};

typedef struct{
    uchar   buttonMask;
    char    dx;
    char    dy;
    char    dWheel;
}report_t;


static report_t reportBuffer;
static uchar    idleRate;

usbMsgLen_t usbFunctionSetup(uchar data[8])
{
    usbRequest_t    *rq = (void *)data;

    /* The following requests are never used. But since they are required by
    * the specification, we implement them in this example.
    */
    if((rq->bmRequestType & USBRQ_TYPE_MASK) == USBRQ_TYPE_CLASS){    /* class request type */
        if(rq->bRequest == USBRQ_HID_GET_REPORT){  /* wValue: ReportType (highbyte), ReportID (lowbyte) */
            /* we only have one report type, so don't look at wValue */
            usbMsgPtr = (void *)&reportBuffer;
            return sizeof(reportBuffer);
            }else if(rq->bRequest == USBRQ_HID_GET_IDLE){
            usbMsgPtr = &idleRate;
            return 1;
            }else if(rq->bRequest == USBRQ_HID_SET_IDLE){
            idleRate = rq->wValue.bytes[1];
        }
    }
    else{
        /* no vendor specific requests implemented */
    }
    return 0;   /* default for not implemented requests: return no data back to host */
}



int main(void)
{
    uchar i;

    wdt_enable(WDTO_1S);

    usbInit();
    usbDeviceDisconnect();  /* enforce re-enumeration, do this while interrupts are disabled! */
    i = 0;
    while(--i){             /* fake USB disconnect for > 250 ms */
        wdt_reset();
        _delay_ms(1);
    }
    usbDeviceConnect();

    UART_Init(9600 , false , true , false);
    UBRRH = 0;
    UBRRL = 0;

    sei();

    while(1)
    {
        wdt_reset();

        usbPoll();

        RecieveUARTdata();


        if(TransmissionComplete && usbInterruptIsReady()){
            /* called after every poll of the interrupt endpoint */
            usbSetInterrupt((void *)&reportBuffer, sizeof(reportBuffer));
        }

    }
    return 0;
}

void ResetValues(){
    X=0;Y=0;
    WaitingForX=false;
    WaitingForY=false;
}



void RecieveUARTdata(){
    //Get the data is available by checking the RXC in UCSRA
    if ( UCSRA & (1<<RXC) )
    {
        uint data = UDR;
        //if the data received is START SYNC DATA
        if(data==START_SYNC_BYTE){
            WaitingForX = true;return;
        }

        else {
            if(WaitingForX){
                X=data; WaitingForX=false;
                WaitingForY=true;return;
            }
            else if(WaitingForY && !WaitingForX){
                Y=data; WaitingForY=false;return;
            }
            else if(!WaitingForX && !WaitingForY && (UDR==END_SYNC_BYTE)){
                reportBuffer.dx = X;
                reportBuffer.dy = Y;
                TransmissionComplete = true;return;
            }else ResetValues();
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I doubt that the UARt module is intended to work with a baud-rate divisor of 0. Try setting it to 1 or 2 at least.

Comment: @brhans UBRR = 0 is fine. \$Baud = Fosc/(16(UBRR+1))\$

Comment: @Akash, you should only read the `UBR` register once, not multiple times. There is a FIFO on the UART block and when you read the register it moves on to the next value in the FIFO.

Comment: `if(UDR==START_SYNC_BYTE){` reads the value then forgets it. `...X=UDR;` reads it a second time which can corrupt the value. You should do `uint8_t in = UDR;` and then `if(in==START_SYNC_BYTE){...X=in;`

Comment: Thirdly, are you using a crystal? If so is it 12MHz? If not, have you calibrated the internal oscillator to 12.8MHz? (you can do this by connecting D- to a interrupt pin and correctly configuring VUSB)

Comment: Yea .. Actually I was doing as u said before but even it didn't work .. I'm using an external crystal of 16 MHz .. I'll update the code ...

Comment: @TomCarpenter I've edited and updated the code

Comment: The other thing is you appear to be sending a 16bit value for X and another for Y. But then you are receiving an 8bit value for X and Y. Where did the other two bytes go?

Comment: Actuallt i'm not bothered about that because my values range from .. 20 to -20 so i'm good with it .. sorry i didnt mentioin it in the question

Comment: Probably unrelated, but shouldn't `sei()` come *before* `usbPoll()`?

Comment: That was a mistake .. Code updated

Comment: What UART library are you using , and what do the Boolean parameters do in `UART_Init(9600 , false , true , false)`?

Comment: Self written library .. 9600 is baud rate .. 1 bool is for tx on .. 2 bool is for RX on .. 3 bool is for interrupt mode on ..

Answer (score 1):

There is one main issue that has been pointed in comments:

```
if ( UCSRA & (1<<RXC) )
{
    uint data = UDR;
    ...
        else if(!WaitingForX && !WaitingForY && (UDR==END_SYNC_BYTE)){
            ...
    }
}
```

In this part you are reading from empty UDR as the `END_SYNC_BYTE` is stored earlier, so this statement is about to be always false.

The less complicated way is to store each incoming byte into FIFO buffer (or even use interrupt based [lib](https://github.com/jnk0le/Easy-AVR-USART-C-Library) that can deal with v-usb) and process entire message in one run.